# UIWebView not showing parsed XML data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a tag `<AboutUs>` (having HTML tags) and I have stored the string part in a local string. Now I want to pass it to my webView to display, but it is showing my string (`null`).

Here's my code, any help is appreciated:

```
@class AppDelegate_iPhone;
@interface AboutUsViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {

    NSMutableString *aboutUsString;
    NSString *currentElement;

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *aboutUsString;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
-(id)init;

@end



@implementation AboutUsViewController
@synthesize aboutUsString,webView;


-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        aboutUsString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
    return self; 
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/AboutUs.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    AboutUsViewController *parser = [[AboutUsViewController alloc] init];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    NSLog(@"After Parsing=== = = = = = = = == = = = = %@",appDelegate.TextString);



}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = elementName;

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"AboutUs"]) {

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"AboutUs"]) {

        NSMutableString *outputBuilder =  [[NSMutableString alloc]init] ;

        [outputBuilder appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.aboutUsString]];

        [outputBuilder appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]];

        self.aboutUsString = outputBuilder;

        [outputBuilder release];

    }
    else 
    {
        self.aboutUsString = string;
    }



}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AboutUs"]) {

        [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
        [webView loadHTMLString:self.aboutUsString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hitchhiker.com/message"]];

        NSLog(@"In DID End Element ===== %@",aboutUsString);

        appDelegate.TextString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:aboutUsString];

    }

    currentElement = @"";
}



- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"In Document End =========  %@",aboutUsString);

    NSLog(@"Appdelgate Text String %@",appDelegate.TextString);


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [webView release];
}


@end
```

Comment: can you also post part of your xml?

Comment: also put NSLog or break points in -parser:foundCharacters: and verify that it is being initialized to some value!

Comment: <p> <font size="2" face="arial" color="white"> <h1> Welcome to Vidushi Infotech </h1>  Out Source Web Design, Graphic Design, Web Development, eCommerce Solutions <br></br> <br></br>Thinking of Out Sourcing your Web development needs to a world class team? Look no further, your search for a custom Web development, Software development, Graphic Design or eCommerce services and  solutions ends here. </font></p>

Comment: Now it is not showing NULL as suggested by omz... but it is not showing my View i wanted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, you're creating a *new* AboutUsViewController which then gets all the `NSXMLParser` delegate calls. It has its own web view, that one will load the parsed HTML, but you'll never see it because the parsing view controller is never actually visible.

You should set `self` as the xml parser's `delegate` instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: Thanks, i have done that, but still now my view is not showing what i am giving to it.

Comment: actually may be is is because i m using TabBar Template.... and its the second view in which i am trying to show webView.... Actually view is loading i think so but my content is not.